# C# DataSource Class and Thread Safety

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, thread-safety

What would be a good way to writein C# a .NET3.5 Thread Safe DataSource Class. The class would connect to SQL Server and every method would execute a Stored Procedure.

When the code worked single threaded. I had a Singleton DataSource Class with a private SqlConnection member. Each method opened and closed that connection. When running this with multiple threads it is causing trouble when under certain scenarios the connection has already been opened by another thread. What would be the best way to re-write this class?

**Note**: By DataSource dont mean any built in .NET class, but a Model class that provides data to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be from the *Singleton* design. That can still work, just make sure you do *not* store the connection as a field. Only use a local variable in each method to hold the connection. That should be thread-safe by design.

And make it Exception-safe as well:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
 {
    // call SP
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use built-in ado.net pooling: create and open the connection right before the operation and dispose is asap - for every method.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server already coordinates threads through very complex mechanisms. You don't need to do anything specific to achieve thread safety to simply execute a Store Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to elaborate more about what your DataSource class should do. You don't need to implement any thread safety code if each of your Create/Read/Update/Delete methods do not alter any state.

UPDATE: In your case, I recommend to just recreate a new `SqlConnection` instance in every method of your DataSource class, because ADO.NET already handles the pooling for you.

Comment: Yes you can surely use a Singleton if you like, especially when your app doesn't connect to multiple databases. (Keep in mind though that the Singleton pattern is deprecated nowadays and it is recommended to use IoC instead).